# Tagging member variables in Python

Tags: python, class

I have a class in python and I want to be able to save the values in it, and be able to load them again. I want to be able to tag the variables that are saveable with different kinds of tags, to be saved in different situations.
For example (with decorator syntax, which showcases how I would like it to work):

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        @saveable(default)
        self.value_1 = 0
        @saveable(default)
        self.value_2 = 1
        @saveable(default, special)
        self.value_3 = 2
    def save_default(self):
        save([i for i in self.saveable.default])
    def save_special(self):
        save([i for i in self.saveable.special])
```

Here, `value_1` and `value_2` are tagged as default, and placed into self.saveable.default and `value_3` is tagged as both default and special, and so is saved for both.

Does anyone have a nice way to do something like this?

Comment: What do you mean by "save" ?

Comment: @Maxime what the save function is doesn't matter; I'm wondering about how to denote them as 'saveable'.

Comment: @timgeb That's what I'm currently doing and I'm wanting a way to avoid doing it, since in these classes I am constantly adding in and removing member variables. It becomes hard to keep track of which ones are tagged with what, and remembering to remove tags when I delete a variable.
Declaring the tags while declaring the variables as illustrated would give this process a lot less friction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

timgeb's answer is probably cleaner, but if you want a concise way to do it you can have a metaclass read type annotations:

```
# bit-masks, though you can use sets or an IntFlag enum
DEFAULT, SPECIAL = 1, 2

class SaveableType(type):
  def __init__(self, name, bases, attrs):
    super().__init__(name, bases, attrs)
    anno = attrs["__annotations__"]
    self.saveable = {"default": [], "special": []}
    for attr_name, value in anno.items():
      if value & DEFAULT:
        self.saveable["default"].append(attr_name)
      if value & SPECIAL:
        self.saveable["special"].append(attr_name)

class C(metaclass=SaveableType):
  value_1: DEFAULT
  value_2: DEFAULT
  value_3: DEFAULT | SPECIAL

print(C.saveable)
```

Comment: Haha, this is hacky - but it might do in my case. I like it.

Answer (score 0):

Plain old `dict`?

```
class Demo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value_1 = 0
        self.value_2 = 1
        self.value_3 = 2

        self.save_flags = dict(
                value_1='default',
                value_2='default',
                value_3='special')

    def save(self, flag):
        template = 'saving {} ({}) with mode {}'

        for attr, savemode in self.save_flags.items():
            if flag == savemode:
                msg = template.format(attr, getattr(self, attr), flag)
                print(msg)

    def save_default(self):
        self.save(flag='default')

    def save_special(self):
        self.save(flag='special')

d = Demo()
d.save_default()
print('----')
d.save_special()
```

Output:

```
saving value_1 (0) with mode default
saving value_2 (1) with mode default
----
saving value_3 (2) with mode special
```

Comment: This is what I'm doing already; I was hoping somebody might be able to come up with a better solution :3

I'll accept it as the answer if nothing better comes up.

Comment: @MaxTyler better in what way? If you need more flexibility, hook into `__setattr__`, `__getattr__`, `__delattr__` to keep the dict up to date. If you need even more flexibility, start writing descriptors. These solutions are unnecessarily complex if you don't need that amount of power, though. I can't say much more without a more descriptive question.